# Filenames in CVS repository garbled due to encoding issues

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, cvs, cp1252

The CVS repo is on a linux box, but the files checked in are from windows clients with names using æ/ø/å. I'm probably the first non-windows user to interact with that repo, and I didn't know about the pitfalls regarding encoding. What happened was that I checked out the repo, and tagged it afterwards. This updated every file, and the ones with special characters got checked in with something else than what it was.

My assumption was that the files' encoding was cp1252, and that tagging these files wouldn't screw up their original encoding. It does however seem like CVS does something weird.

The problem now is that the repo contains files with invalid encoding that CVS doesn't understand, so I cant do anything about them. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with Windows 2000 and CVS/TortoiseCVS which was the OS where the files were comitted from. Checking the files out on newer Windows versions would also give garbled results. Mounting the W2000 box as a disk an manually copying the files helped.